# How to fix: "TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: order_by"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm updating the Django version in a project, I've never done that before and I'm facing a lot of problems, one of them is this one, and so far I couldn't find the solution.

Full error description:
**File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 358, in get_filters raise TypeError(TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: order_by) **

**Here are the requirements I'm currently using:**

```
arabic-reshaper==3.0.0
asgiref==3.7.2
astroid==2.4.2
autopep8==1.5.4
boto3==1.13.3
botocore==1.16.3
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
cssselect2==0.7.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.1
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
django-allauth==0.53.0
django-translation==1.2
django-after-response==0.2.2
django-cors-headers==3.2.1
django-crispy-forms==1.9.1
django-ebhealthcheck==1.0.1
django-extensions==2.2.9
django-filter==2.4.0
django-sass==1.0.0
django-seed==0.2.2
django-storages==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-filters==1.0.0.dev2
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.5.0
docutils==0.15.2
Faker==4.0.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
html5lib==1.1
idna==2.9
isort==5.4.2
jmespath==0.9.5
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
libsass==0.20.0
lxml==4.9.2
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.24.2
pandas==1.3.5
Pillow==9.4.0
psycopg2==2.8.4
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pydot==1.4.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.6.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
PyPDF2==1.26.0
PyPDF3==1.0.6
python-bidi==0.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.7.1
reportlab==3.6.12
requests==2.23.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
selenium==3.141.0
sentry-sdk==0.14.4
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
svglib==1.5.1
text-unidecode==1.3
tinycss2==1.2.1
toml==0.10.1
tqdm==4.65.0
urllib3==1.25.9
webencodings==0.5.1
whitenoise==5.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
xhtml2pdf==0.2.6
xlrd==1.2.0
```

**here are the old requirements:**

```
arabic-reshaper==3.0.0
asgiref==3.2.7
astroid==2.4.2
autopep8==1.5.4
boto3==1.13.3
botocore==1.16.3
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
cssselect2==0.7.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.5
django-after-response==0.2.2
django-cors-headers==3.2.1
django-crispy-forms==1.9.1
django-ebhealthcheck==1.0.1
django-extensions==2.2.9
django-filter==2.2.0
django-sass==1.0.0
django-seed==0.2.2
django-storages==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
djangorestframework-filters==1.0.0.dev0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.5.0
docutils==0.15.2
Faker==4.0.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
html5lib==1.1
idna==2.9
isort==5.4.2
jmespath==0.9.5
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
libsass==0.20.0
lxml==4.9.2
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.24.2
pandas==1.3.5
Pillow==9.4.0
psycopg2==2.8.4
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pydot==1.4.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pylint==2.6.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
PyPDF2==1.26.0
PyPDF3==1.0.6
python-bidi==0.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.7.1
reportlab==3.6.12
requests==2.23.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
selenium==3.141.0
sentry-sdk==0.14.4
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
svglib==1.5.1
text-unidecode==1.3
tinycss2==1.2.1
toml==0.10.1
tqdm==4.65.0
urllib3==1.25.9
webencodings==0.5.1
whitenoise==5.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
xhtml2pdf==0.2.6
xlrd==1.2.0
```

I got this error after updating

**djangorestframework-filters==1.0.0.dev0**

for

**djangorestframework-filters==1.0.0.dev2**

Comment: Share the *full* traceback.